# css columns / flexbox with no gaps between items

Tags: javascript, css

I need to get rid of gaps between elements in my column layout. I can use the latest css3 as the site is targeted at modern browsers/devices but I need to avoid a javascript solution such that the page as delivered from the server doesn't need to be re-rendered based on the width of the client.

Using flexbox, css columns, and other tricks I need to coax a pinterest-like layout. (Pinterest uses javascript and absolute positioning for their layout, it doesn't even render with js turned off.) The site has boxes with a known width but variable height. The number of columns needs to vary based on browser width. (I can do this via media queries if I know what css attribute to change.) Here's what this looks like: [via](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/)

[image: gaps]

Also note that I can't just increase the height of the containers to fill the empty space. I want to bring the item below it UP, not make all the heights match. (So stretching items 1, 3, and 4 in the picture above is NOT what I want.)

Things I've tried:

- CSS 3 columns. This looks great, but the items are in the wrong order, with the second item being under the first. If this can be changed to a different order such that they go left-to-right, great!
- Flexbox various flexbox configurations, I've tried just about every setting that I was able to change.
- Javascript. Yes, I know I can manually create columns and re-render them on resize. I'm looking to avoid an expensive re-render operation that requires a manual balancing of columns and display. I can resort to this for older browsers that don't support a css3 solution. I'm also wanting to avoid manually positioning all of the items. Gross.

I've put a comment link to JSFiddle because I can't put it in here as "links to jsfiddle require code".

Comment: Masonry? http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: take a look at this link: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ it might help you out.

Comment: use : align-self: stretch; , so on each row all boxes will take  height of the highest to fill gaps in between rows/lines.

Comment: @sinisterfrog Masonry looks cool, but I'm looking for a non-js solution

Comment: @dippas - I'm not looking to stretch my items down, but rather bring the items below them up. I've made that more clear in my question now.

Comment: @GCyrillus - I'm not looking to stretch my items down, but rather bring the items below them up. I've made that more clear in my question now.

Comment: That's not possible without js...

Comment: @WillShaver , i understood, i just pointed at a compromise possible via CSS. if you use display:flex;, else you have column CSS and avoid breaking each container wich sends back eventually to masonry script.

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or jsfiddle, so we get your structure and can propose you advise or work around upon what you did/have

Comment: well then it depends on which order you want your items, if you want ltr (4 by 2) [ as you have in your image] instead top to bottom (2 by 4) I can't see any dynamic  solution in CSS.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vkt62/

Comment: you have a few options.  option 1 is to use equal height with flexbox, but that means you will increase the height on the shorter containers. option 2 would be to use negative margin to pull up the containers. *no a good solutions since you will need to have hard heights. option 3 is to use js library like masonry/isotope.

Answer (score 7):

check this demo. This is pure css3 masonry effect.
http://w3bits.com/labs/css-masonry/

spinet from above link

```css
body {
    font: 1em/1.67 'Open Sans', Arial, Sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background: #e9e9e9;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 3em auto;
}

.masonry {
    margin: 1.5em 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.5em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.5em;
    column-gap: 1.5em;
    font-size: .85em;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 0 #ccc;
}
.item.black{
background-color: #000; height:200px;}
.item.blue{
background-color:blue; height:250px;}
.item.green{
background-color:green; height:300px;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        column-count: 5;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 1260px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
   <div class="item black">...</div>
   <div class="item blue">...</div>
   <div class="item green">...</div>
  <div class="item black">...</div>
   <div class="item blue">...</div>
   <div class="item green">...</div>
  <div class="item black">...</div>
   <div class="item blue">...</div>
   <div class="item green">...</div>
</div>
```

Hope this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by flexbox:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  max-width: 900px;
  height: 470px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.item {
  height: 150px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/asim-coder/pen/vXzKgg

Comment: Container needing a set height would make this not dynamic enough to be practical

Answer (score 1):

CSS3: Set the main ul li that holds all 8 drop-down panels to margin: 0 auto;

```
mainList li {
   margin: 0 auto; /*0 giving no margins on the top and bottom of the panels, and auto making the panels use all of the space within the parent, mainList. I hope this helps.*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a little bit late, may be this could be a solution.

I am using flex as it is the only system that can change the order as you want.

The drawbacks of this method is that I need to use some artificial elements to act as separators, and that I need to set a predetermined height on the container

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 90%;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.item {
  height: 150px;
  width: 24%;
  margin: 2px;
}
.item:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  height: 200px;
}
.item:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  height: 250px;
}
.item:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: orange;
  order: 40;
}
.item:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  background-color: green;
  order: 10;
}
.item:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  order: 20;
}
.item:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  background-color: yellow;
  order: 30;
}
.divider {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
.divider:nth-last-child(3) {
  order: 15;
}
.divider:nth-last-child(2) {
  order: 25;
}
.divider:nth-last-child(1) {
  order: 35;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use http://desandro.github.io/masonry/ Masonry will help to solve your issue, it is what Pinterest uses. My company is currently using it to develope a program, it is very easy and user friendly.

Comment: Masonry is cool and all, but as stated plainly in the question I'm not looking for a javascript solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, things like this need to be accomplished with JS. There is another solution, try to make your columns separate divs, and make no rows, this should allow each section to stack in the column, and then allow each column to stack horizontally giving the desired effect.